# Should "whom" be capitalized in a title?

Tags: capitalization

As in the title of the book *For whom the Bells Toll*, should the word "whom" be capitalized?

---

Also, any advice on when to capitalize within a title would be appreciated.

Comment: Most style guides would say yes. Which style guide are you following?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? It's the referent of the title, and its only human NP. Have you actually looked it up? As for rules, the simplest rule is to capitalize the first word and any proper names, just like regular print. Anything more is on your own esthetic hook, or else copied from the actual print.